# Accessibility of the my app is continuesly disabled

Tags: android, accessibility

I used accessibility in my app. I used below code to enable the accessibility to the my app. In android 7.0 version it is working good but in 6.0 and 8.0 it is continuously disable the accessbility to the my app when i clear the instance of my app.

```
        this.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS), 400);
```

Please anyone help to resolve my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this link will help you.. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137195/accessibility-services-gets-disabled-automatically

Comment: @code4rox  don't see that option in my battery settings.